# Html/JS/PHP two pages using the same files look different (only in chrome)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

On one of my fake domains I've been working on a menu for fun. The menu works as expected here:

-Removed-

However, that page doesn't use any PHP.

-Removed-

This page does use PHP to fill the links in the menu from a database full of fake links. The problem is that it works as expected in IE9 but chrome for some reason adds a left:40px to the div that holds the links the first time you load the page. Afterwords, the script looks and acts as it is supposed to. I validated the html and CSS as XHTML 1.0 Strict and CSS3. I have not been able to test this in Firefox or opera because this computer cannot have those browsers installed.

The only difference HTML wise is that in the php version, the links are actually tagged as links were as the homepage version, they are simply text. The CSS does contain styles for the  element in the .LinkDiv class that sets margins and padding to 0px.

If anyone is able to shine some light on this issue, that would be great.

I added:

```
.LinkDiv {
height: 100px;
width: 175px;
display: none;
position: relative;
left: 0; /* This */
background-color: rgb(217,217,217);
}
```

and constantly hit refresh, sometimes in chrome it loaded correctly, others it loaded with the div 40px to the left.

Comment: You should be able in Chrome to see where each CSS style property comes from in the _Resolved style_ section...

Comment: Can you replicate a static example in a fiddle? Or at least post some code...

Comment: Did you note that HTML code is pretty different? I would be surprised if they render exactly the same even without any CSS reset...

Comment: `o load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://phovze.com/menu/images/These.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://phovze.com/menu/images/Fake.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://phovze.com/menu/images/Are.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
`
this is part of the error from chrome console.

this is what you need to fix

Comment: @Adriano I am not familiar with that tool, I attempted to do a quick google for information but I couldn't find anything. Do you have a link to a resource surrounding the "resolved style" section? The styles section in the developer tool shows it as an inline style.
Jonathan, I could post the code if you'd like but its fairly large. I have never worked with fiddle so I can't verify if I could "replicate" it.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan it's referring to the background image for the TVContainer div. This is not related to the issue and is because the URL in the javascript that updates the background image uses a relative path rather than absolute and the relative path changed when the file was placed in a different directory. Im confident this isn't part of the issue.

Comment: @Adriano The only difference html wise is the A tags which I did mention in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to you css file

```
.LinkDiv:nth-child(1){left:0 !important;}
```

Comment: My concern is that the javascript does change the left property of the div. If I set it as you suggested, would this prevent the JS from changing it as needed?

Comment: yes java script change the property, if you use firebug you can see there is in line style for the div, you can also change this inline style from your js file.

Comment: As far as cam tell this fixed the loading issue but now the div doesn't move the way it's suppose to.

Comment: Aye, it works now. Thanks. I have a feeling the issue is some how related to chromes desire to cache data rather than re-execute scripts.